# Scope missing in access token claims in Azure B2C OAuth Client credential flow

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/client-credentials-grant-flow?pivots=b2c-user-flow) to register an application (App) resource which would have limited access to another (API) resource which is also registered with the tenant. I've exposed that API scope which has been registered in the API permissions for that particular scope in the (App) resource as below.

[image]

I have also generated a client secret and attempted to retrieve a token using the `client-credentials` grant type. While it returns a valid token. It doesn't appear to contain the `scp` claim which should be the `access_as_*****` value. How might I get this claim to appear in the token response when the `access_token` is decoded?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Please note that, **`client-credentials`** grant type works with **Application** permissions only. As your exposed API scope is **Delegated**, it won't work with **`client-credentials`** grant type.

In addition to that, you are using **wrong token endpoint** to generate the token.

You can get **`token endpoint`** of your application like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure AD B2C -> App registrations -> Your App -> Overview -> Endpoints***

[image]

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I have registered an API application and created **`AppRole`** by changing its manifest like below:

```json
"appRoles": [
{
"allowedMemberTypes": [
"Application"
],
"description": "Access API",
"displayName": "Demo",
"id": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx",
"isEnabled": true,
"lang": null,
"origin": "Application",
"value": "access_as_api"
}
],
```

**Manifest of MyAPI:**

[image]

To generate the id, you can user either **PowerShell** or [**online GUID generator**](https://www.bing.com/search?q=online+guid+generator)

I added this **API scope** in my application like below:

[image]

Make sure to **grant consent** for that added permission and it is of **Application** type:

[image]

I generated the access token using  **`client-credentials`** grant type like below:

[image]

***I got the **`scp`** claim successfully when I decoded the token like below:***

[image]

Comment: Yes that's what I was missing. I needed to configure the manifest for the API app and register using the correct permission type. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The strange thing is the appRoles are return as "scp" (Scope) claim and not "roles" claim. This causes trouble when using the MSAL library. That's really weird.

Comment: @Sven: If you use the .WithB2CAuthority during the confidential client creation, then your tokens will come with the scope claim as "scp" instead as of "roles". However, if you remove it, the scope claim will come as "roles"

            'ConfidentialClientApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
                .WithB2CAuthority(AuthoritySignUpSignIn)
                .WithTenantId(TenantId)
                .WithRedirectUri(RedirectUri)
                .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
                 .Build();'