# Missing 'roles' or 'scp' claim in B2C token client credentials flow

Tags: azure-authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I registered one application in my B2C tenant. I created client secret and added permissions like openid and offline_access.

I got the access token with scope as `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` using client_credentials flow from Postman.

But when I decoded the token, I can't find either `roles` or `scp` claim in it. I am expecting openid and offline_access in the decoded token.

I am thinking of changing the flow to authorization code but I can't find any working example of getting tokens for B2C applications using auth code flow. Mostly I'm getting examples for Azure AD tenants, not B2C. But my requirement is for B2C tenants.

Token parameters I used are:

```
POST https://login.microsoft.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: my_app_id
grant_type: client_credentials
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
client_secret: my_client_secret
```

I think there is nothing wrong with my parameters as I got access token? Or am I missing any?

Comment: Could you include the token endpoint and the parameters you used by editing it?

Comment: @SrideviM edited with token parameters.

Comment: You are using wrong token endpoint, refer this ***[SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73416245/scope-missing-in-access-token-claims-in-azure-b2c-oauth-client-credential-flow/73440479#73440479)*** of mine.

Comment: That is related to Application permissions, I want for delegated permissions

Comment: I changed token endpoint now, getting `AADB2C90085: The service has encountered an internal error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please **note** that, Delegated permissions  won't work with **client_credentials flow.**

***I got the same error as you when I used below parameters to get access token:***

```
POST https://<tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy_name>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: my_app_id
grant_type: client_credentials
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
client_secret: my_client_secret
```

**Response:**

[image]

As **`openid`** and **`offline_access`** are delegated permissions, you need to use authorization code flow to get tokens:

- **`openid`** - This scope is used to get ***ID token*** for the application.
- **`offline_access`** - This scope is used to get  ***Refresh token*** for the application.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I have registered one Azure AD B2C application and added permissions like this:

[image]

In order to generate access token using ***auth code flow***, you need to get **`code`** using below query:

```
https://<tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy_name>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=your_client_id&nonce=12345&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms &scope=openid offline_access&response_type=code
```

You need to sign in to your account and you will get **`code`** in the address bar like below:

[image]

I generated tokens using ***auth code flow*** via **Postman** with below parameters:

```
POST https://<tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy_name>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: your_app_id
grant_type: authorization_code
scope: openid offline_access
client_secret: your_client_secret
code: //code you got from above query
```

***Response:***

[image]

The response includes only **id token** and **refresh token** as scope is `openid offline_access`

If you want **`scp`** claims in the decoded access token, you need to **Expose an API** and grant API permission for it by changing the **scope** accordingly.

**Reference:**
[Request an access token - B2C | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens)

Comment: It means openid and offline_access won't give access token right?

Comment: No, you will get only id token and refresh token with those scopes

Comment: You need to expose the API and grant consent to that scope to get `scp` claim.