# Azure AD B2C call Registered App endpoint from Custom Policy

Tags: c#, .net, azure, webapi, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to call my Web Api from registration Custom Policy. To do that, i need to authenticate first and get token. I want to use client_credentials grant_type. I can acquire token in postman using request and client id with client secret:

```
https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignInPolicy/oauth2/v2.0/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=---client_id------&client_secret=-----client_secret----&scope=https://mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/myRegisteredApp/.default
```

I added scope by editing Manifest file and adding App Role.

When I try to call that endpoint from CustomPolicy, i get BadRequest all the time. I try to add technical profile like following:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="REST-AcquireAccessToken">
 <DisplayName></DisplayName>
 <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
 <Metadata>
   <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignInPolicy/oauth2/v2.0/token
  </Item>
  <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Basic</Item>
  <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Form</Item>
  <Item Key="DebugMode">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SecureRESTClientId" />
    <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SecureRESTClientSecret" /> 
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="client_credentials" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="https://mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/myRegisteredApp/.default" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="bearerToken" PartnerClaimType="access_token" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

The same technical profile works when I change serviceUrl for:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

or Entra endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

but then I get my scope as "Roles" and API doesn't accept token withount "scp" property.

**Question**: Can I call my Policy endpoint from Policy, or can I somehow ignore missing scope from Web API?

Comment: I am receiving the same issue. I would raise an official Microsoft Support ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more debugging and documentation, i understood the problem. As documentation says among others [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles?tabs=aspnetcore), **token** which we wanna use to authorize request in, for example, our API, **must contain "scp" (scope) OR "roles" prop written in token**. If we have real user, after succsfull authorization on *.../token* enpoint we will receive in response token with "scp" prop, but if this is non-interactive flow from apllication, we will get "roles" attribute. Role is something like scope but for application. So I was getting proper response, but i was reading it wrong.

**TL;DR:** Token with "scp" and token with "roles" has different Issuers, Authorities and Audiences, so if you have, like me, already configured authorization for B2C users ([with docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-api?tabs=csharpclient)) you have to configure separate schemas for each token (user and application) and set proper values for above properties.

In final solution i took the following (really detailed, sorry not sorry) steps:

First part is created using answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73416245/scope-missing-in-access-token-claims-in-azure-b2c-oauth-client-credential-flow).

1. I was using AD B2C, so I don't have "App roles" menu option in registered app, but you can achieve the same in B2C by putting "appRoles" node in registered app Manifest:

```
"appRoles": [
 {
  "allowedMemberTypes": [
    "Application"
  ],
  "description": "Access API",
  "displayName": "Demo",
  "id": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "lang": null,
  "origin": "Application",
  "value": "access_as_api"
 }
],
```

where id is just a GUID generated on [generator here](https://guidgenerator.com/) using Hypens option.  What's important you need unique "value" for you scope.

2. After you create Role, you need to add it in API Permissions
   (Add Permission/My APIs/Application Permissions) and grant Admin Consent for this permission. Important; when i was testing this and changing values od scopes, I had some bug on Azure, when I was getting authorization error any time I was trying to save Manifest, delete users or, well, do anything - my editing left some empty, broken object in API permissions, when I deleted this, it was all back to normal

Thats a short version of those two steps, as more details you can find in stack answer i linked above. Now, when those two steps was complited I was getting 401, as stated in my question. Thankfully, i configured Swagger Authorization Bearer schema, and as I used ngrok to serve Web API endpoint for Azure Policy, I could get token generated by azure from ngrok web page which showed all requests for this addres with all the headers (thats where i could copy token from Authorization Header) and i could paste it in Swagger options

Configuration for debugging:

- ngrok console i got after running ngrok *http http://localhost:5089 --host-header=rewrite* (remember, web API must run on http):
  [ngrog web interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neSP4.png)
- swagger:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme",
            Name = "Authorization",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
            Scheme = "Bearer"
        });
        c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        { 
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "Bearer"
                    },
                    Scheme = "oauth2",
                    Name = "Bearer",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header
                },
                new List<string>()
            } 
        });
        var filePath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "MyAppName.xml");
        c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
    });
```

3. THEN when I used token from ngrok in Swagger input for token, I finally got error which was stopping my token. I had already configured authorization for users using Bearer Shema. Errors was saying, i had "Invalid Issuer: "" ", and when i solved this by adding

```
options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers
```

I got errors about invalid signature. From there it was easy to find final solution by reading some stacks, fist from google search:

I needed to configure two separate Authentication schemas, set JwtBearr Schema for users as deafult, and for each schema set ValidIssuers, Authority and Audience options.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer("custom_policy", options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role;
                options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = nameClaimType;
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = [ "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant id/v2.0"];
                options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant id/v2.0";
                options.Audience = registered app id);
            })
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role;
                options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = nameClaimType;
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = [ "https://yourtenant.b2clogin.com/tenant id/v2.0"];
                options.Authority = "https://yourtenant.b2clogin.com/tenant id/v2.0";
                options.Audience = registered app id);

                options.Events = <...>
            }, options => { builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); }, "Bearer");

    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("new-policy", policy =>
        {
            policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add("custom_policy");
            policy.RequireRole("access_as_api");
        });

        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    });
```

4. Last step is to set proper attributes for methods, for method for azure cstom policy, attribute was:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "access_as_api", AuthenticationSchemes = "custom_policy")]
```